# Plurality of a collection

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Take the sentence: *Update the titles of each document*

Should *title(s)* be plural?

I am unsure because there are multiple titles since we have a collection of documents but only referring to a single one at a time.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your main question, but you can work around this by rephrasing: "_Update each document's title_"

Comment: @ryanyuyu in that sentence document's is still singular right? the s is to show possession?

Comment: Yes that's correct. The "each" helps convey the collection of individual documents.

Comment: or you can use "update the titles in/of all the documents"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not be plural.

Here, in combination with *each*, *titles* would mean that every document has multiple titles. So, your sentence should be:

> Update the title of each document.

If you want *titles* to be in the plural, put *document* in the plural form:

> Update the titles of all documents.

Alternatively, you can rephrase the sentence. Have a look at the numerous examples given in the comments on your question.

Comment: Why do you use "the" article with plural "titles"? I thought we do not need any article here at all.